# Query by date range using Mongoose for dates that have format MM/DD/YY h:m and type String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
    const someSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
{
   updatedAt: { type: string }
}, { timestamps: { currentTime: () => moment().format("MM/DD/YY, h:mm") } }

);
```

I want to query this collection to find the documents updated within a  date range for example:
12/05/20 to 12/31/20, hours and minutes don't matter. My startDate and endDate is in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I have tried to find

```
updatedAt: {
                    $gte: new Date(startDate),
                    $lte: new Date(endDate)
                }
```

or

```
updatedAt: {
                        $gte: startDate,
                        $lte: endDate
                    }
```

but they are not working. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Don't store your dates in a human readable format. Store them in a format Mongo can understand and query (type:Date). Transform the dates to human-readable format only when you want to display them, not in your database.

Comment: Storing date/time values as **string** is a design flaw, you should never do this. Store proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

First try to alter `moment().format("MM/DD/YY, h:mm")`
to `moment().format("MM/DD/YY, HH:MM:SS")`

then

```
updatedAt: { $gte: new Date(startDate).setHours(0,0,0,0)
             $lte: new Date(endDate).setHours(0,0,0,0)},
```

You are declaring moment().format as a datetime but when you create Date() object you are passing only the date!

When you are practicing date manipulation better use milliseconds and UTC notation. It is something universal to all type of databases. Avoid to use varchar type to store date as strings.

Give it a try!

Comment: That's as bad - use `moment().toDate()` or `moment().startOf('day').toDate()` if you don't care about the time.